# htaccess If...Else always selects Else

Tags: apache, .htaccess, environment-variables, apache2.4

I set an environment variable in **httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
SetEnv EARLY_VAR 1
```

I try setting special rules based on its value in **.htaccess**

```
<If "%{ENV:EARLY_VAR} == '1'">
   SetEnv TEST_VAR  if_branch
</If>
<Else>
    SetEnv TEST_VAR  else_branch
</Else>
```

I expect `TEST_VAR` environment var to equal `if_branch`.  In **PHP**

```
var_dump(getenv('EARLY_VAR')); // string '1'
var_dump(getenv('TEST_VAR')); // string 'else_branch'
```

I also tried setting `EARLY_VAR` in `.htaccess` above the If/Else, both using `SetEnv` and `SetEnvIf`.  Always the *Else* branch is executed.

Why is this?

`Apache 2.4`

Comment: Not seeing `%{ENV:` as a valid expression here ~ http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html. There is the `env` function though

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the tip. The documentation language on that page is difficult to understand but I think you put me on the right track

Comment: @Phil `%{ENV:` is also valid.and would be expanded as `"%{" funcname ":" funcargs "}"`

Comment: @hjpotter92 can you link to some documentation for that?

Comment: @Phil The link that you provided, under the section for Bachus Naur grammar, see the expansion of `variable`. The list of functions is also provided a little down the page.

Comment: I just tried to doc the risk of using envvars in <If> conditions in the manual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without using expression i.e. `if/else` directives you can do this:

```
# set EARLY_VAR to 1
SetEnvIf Host ^ EARLY_VAR=1

# if EARLY_VAR is 1 then set TEST_VAR to if_branch
SetEnvIf EARLY_VAR ^1$ TEST_VAR=if_branch

# if EARLY_VAR is NOT 1 then set TEST_VAR to else_branch
SetEnvIf EARLY_VAR ^(?!1$) TEST_VAR=else_branch
```

This will work with even older Apache versions i.e. `<2.4`

---

**EDIT:**

In your Apache config or vhost config have this variable initialization:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^ EARLY_VAR=5
```

Then in your .htaccess you can use:

```
<If "env('EARLY_VAR') == '5'">
   SetEnv TEST_VAR if_branch
</If>
<Else>
   SetEnv TEST_VAR else_branch
</Else>
```

Reason why you need env variable declaration in Apache/vhost config because .htaccess is loaded after Apache/vhost config and env variables set in same .htaccess are not available for evaluation in `if/else` expressions.

Also, note that it is important to use `SetEnvIf` instead of `SetEnv` to make these variables available to `if/else` expressions.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using `<if>` and `<else>` because I want to wrap a big block of many directives for two different environments.  I used `SetEnv` within the blocks just as a quick way for me to check from my PHP script which branch was executed.  I don't actually need to set that `TEST_VAR`. It's a placeholder for a group of directives.

Comment: Well explained.  It worked on my dev machine but on the server I get error `/path/.htaccess: Invalid command 'SetEnv', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration` So to set `TEST_VAR` in htaccess I did `SetEnvIf Host ^ TEST_VAR=if_branch`. Thank you

Comment: The problem here is that variables referenced in the <If> itself are resolved as close to immediately after htaccess files are parsed.  

Therefore any module which can be configured in htaccess invariable runs after <if>.

mod_setenvif is somewhat unique in that it can run its code early when you put it outside of any configuration section. Almost no other module does that.

I think the best pattern here is to try to shoe-horn into directives that take expressions as conditionals

Comment: @anubhava. I was specifically looking for this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#if. But I was able to find it within the page you linked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For more detailed docs, please refer: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the documentation of [`SetEnv` directive](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_env#setenv), I notice:

> Sets an internal environment variable, which is then available to
>   Apache HTTP Server modules, and passed on to CGI scripts and SSI
>   pages.

which means that the environments are then available to other modules. Whereas, `<if>` directive is provided by the core. This can be confirmed if you try to see whether the environment is empty during the `<if>` clause:

```
<If "-z %{ENV:EARLY_VAR}">
   SetEnv TEST_VAR  if_branch
</If>
```

or

```
<If "-z env('EARLY_VAR')">
   SetEnv TEST_VAR  if_branch
</If>
```

both will give you:

```
string(1) "1" string(9) "if_branch"
```

in your PHP.

---

There is also the following caveat listed on the Apache's [environment variables wiki/docs](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/env) pages:

> The `SetEnv` directive runs late during request processing meaning
>   that directives such as `SetEnvIf` and `RewriteCond` will not see the
>   variables set with it.

Comment: Thanks for your input and tests. Does this mean that I cannot use `If/Else` branching based on an environment var? In particular a var set in the same `.htaccess`.  Perhaps it could work with a var set through `SetEnvIf`?

Comment: @BeetleJuice Not in the same context, no! You'd have to set the environment at a context at least one level above the `<if>` directive location.

Comment: See comment under @anubhava's answer for a description of what unique thing is going on here. It is not an issue of an enclosing section, because that would not affect the execution timing.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could make it work is using [SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) both in `.conf` and `.htaccess`:

I used only this in `.conf`

```
SetEnvIf Server_Addr ^ EARLY_VAR=1
```

and then only this in `.htaccess` :

```
SetEnvIf EARLY_VAR ^ TEST_VAR=else_branch
SetEnvIf EARLY_VAR ^1$ TEST_VAR=if_branch
```

(without `If` directive. Whatever I tried within `If`, it seemed like it was evaluated before EARLY_VAR is set)

Comment: Please specify whether you mean that you did one or the other, or you had to do both (`.conf` and `.htaccess` settings). Please also show the expression within `<If ...>` as well.

Comment: No `If` unfortunately, so the usability of this approach is quite limited

Answer (score 0):

If you found problem with SetEnv and SetEnvIf in your Apache configuration.

**Set the variable in `httpd.conf` file as below**

```
SetEnvIf Host ".*" EARLY_VAR=1
SetEnvIf Host eval EARLY_VAR=1
SetEnvIf Host dev EARLY_VAR=1
```

It assign the value in all type of server `(production ,evaluation or development)`

**Now you can use your variable in `.htaccess` file**.

```
<IF "%{ENV:EARLY_VAR} == 1">
    SetEnv TEST_VAR if_value
</IF>
<ELSE>
    SetEnv TEST_VAR else_value
</ELSE>
```