# Apache 2.4: Precedence of IF Rules?

Tags: apache2.4

I have, in this order, this set of rules in `.htaccess`, processed by Apache 2.4.33:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(subdomain\.olddomain)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^               https://www.example.com/directory/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

## for some of the specific rules below
RewriteBase /

<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /^(?:.*\.)?olddomain\.(?:com|net)$/i">

    ## some other specific rules which do not fire

    RewriteRule ^               https://%1example.com/directory%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</If>
```

However, it seems that the `If` block with the general rule set takes precedence although it follows the more specific first one rewriting to a different URL and terminated with `L`.

Changing `(?:.*\.)?` to `(?:www\.)?` things work as expected. Also if the first rule set is moved into the `If` block (more efficient code anyway, but things have evolved).

I have read, amongst others, [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/59665/precedence-of-rewriterules-in-htaccess-file-on-apache-server) posting which I understand but can't apply to the case here as the first rule, if fired, should rewrite the domain/host and therefore should not match the `If` condition anymore.

@covener's comment to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462219/2143912) posting mentions a precedence with regard to variables/modules, too, but is there a more general documentation? (I've read both the directive and the referenced article on expressions in TFM, noting the remark on `If` preceding authentication, too).

TIA for any suggestion a/o explanation.

Comment: Sorry looks like your tag wasn't really a tag and I never saw this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like another subtle behavior in how directives are merged, and another one in which mod_rewrite is slightly non-standard.

Essentially what's happening here is that when the `<If>` matches, the enclosed RewriteRules are considered a new "configuration section" to be merged with the previous one for the modules whose directives appear.

But, mod_rewrite REPLACES previous configurations sections with new ones by default. They are not merged together. There are directives that control it under RewriteOptions.

It is really non-intuitive how directives configurations are evaluated, merged, then executed in three distinct phases.  In the conf file, they just look like code that would be stepped through as encountered.

Comment: In line with your comment referenced on the other thread I now understand that `.htaccess` is first read in entirely and matching `If`blocks executed before (almost) any other directives, right? Along with the non-merge policy of `mod_rewrite` this makes sense with regard to the observed behaviour.

Comment: As said we have moved all subdomain/olddomain rewrite rules into the `If` block meanwhile (also for optimization), but it still will help understand preference and flow of directives in future cases. Thanks. (Accidentally had hit `Enter` on the previous comment and couldn't edit it anymore within the 5-minutes limit.)